# What does it mean to be “stable to deformation”?

Tags: neural-network, image-classification

In the context of image classification, what does it mean to be stable to deformation? Say I were trying to classify digits, what would the difference be between an operation that is stable vs unstable to deformation?

Comment: Could you provide some context? I think you are talking about afine transformations and models that are robust to such transformations, but I can't be sure. Where did you see this?

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte This is the paper I'm referencing: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1513.pdf. In section 1 paragraph 3, it seems to differentiate between invariance and stability.

Answer (score 1):

Images are susceptible to deformations, i.e. afine or arbitrary deformations, such as "melting" effects.

In computer vision algorithms for non-constrained environments it may be desirable for a predictive model to be **"stable", i.e. robust, ideally invariant, to arbitrary transformations that are common in that problem.** *E.g. a digit classifier would benefit from been stable to common paper deformations such as those caused by wrapping and unwrapping a long letter.*

It is said that pooling layers insert certain stability to these deformations, this is analysed by Ruderman on his paper [Learned Deformation Stability in Convolutional Neural Networks](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6f5d/4ab71b3ede46b70f678ebc919312d620c8c7.pdf) and in [Pooling is neither necessary nor sufficient for
appropriate deformation stability in CNNs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.04438.pdf).

Some features, such as SIFT, BRISK and HoG try to deal with the most common deformations in image (Scale and Rotation). Most of convolution-dependent methods are already invariant to shifting as that is a feature of convolutional filtering itself.